# Erlang Meck: How does one mock only a specific function clause?

Tags: erlang, meck

Give a function with multiple clauses, I'd want to mock only a specific case and for every other input that would otherwise cause a 'function_clause' error, I'd want to have it handled by the original function. It's almost like a selective passthrough in erlang meck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [`meck:passthrough/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/meck/meck.html#passthrough-1):
I created a module with a function like this:

```
-module(demo).
-export([original/1]).

original(1) -> one;
original(2) -> two;
original(3) -> three.
```

Then on the console…

```
1> meck:new(demo).
ok
2> meck:expect(demo, original,
2>             fun (1) -> not_one
2>               ; (Arg) -> meck:passthrough([Arg])
2>             end).
ok
3> demo:original(1).
not_one
4> demo:original(2).
two
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: How to bypass the foreign key constraint using meck

Comment: What's "the foreign key constraint"?